# Count distinct one column based on criteria on another few columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have sample data::
[Data-Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU2bx.png)

```
  Country   Year  Month  CustID   Sales    Point   TestSUM  OrderType 
 Singapore  2018     10  AAA      623.96      520  1143.96          1 
 Singapore  2018     10  AAA       92.16        0    92.16          3 
 Singapore  2018     11  AAA     1168.28  1002.86  2171.14          1 
 Singapore  2018     11  BBB      118.58   103.25   221.83          1 
 Singapore  2018     10  CCC      118.88   103.25   222.13          1 
 Singapore  2018     11  CCC      278.67   217.75   496.42          1 
 Singapore  2018     11  CCC     -108.72   -94.75  -203.47          2 
 Singapore  2018     11  CCC           0        0        0          3 
 Singapore  2018     10  DDD      446.14    385.9   832.04          1 
 Singapore  2018     11  DDD      138.95      121   259.95          1 
 Singapore  2018     11  DDD     -228.07        0  -228.07          2 
 Singapore  2018     10  EEE      905.32    796.5  1701.82          1 
 Singapore  2018     10  EEE     -405.75  -357.75   -763.5          2 
 Singapore  2018     10  EEE       29.66        0    29.66          3 
 Singapore  2018     11  EEE       147.8      127    274.8          1 
 Singapore  2018     10  FFF           0        0        0          3 
 Singapore  2018     10  GGG           0        0        0          3 
 Singapore  2018     10  HHH      120.57    104.5   225.07          1 
 Singapore  2018     10  HHH           0        0        0          3 
 Singapore  2018     11  HHH      189.59   165.25   354.84          1 
 Singapore  2018     10  JJJ      117.12   100.25   217.37          1 
 Singapore  2018     10  JJJ           0        0        0          3 
 Singapore  2018     11  JJJ      291.53   254.25   545.78          1
```

and I am trying to calculate distinct 'CustID' based on 2 criteria which is in 3 columns:

1. 'Sales' AND 'Points' cannot both be '0'
2. 'OrderType' is only in (1, 2, 3)

Hence I created an additional column 'TestSUM' that sums 'Sales' and 'Points' which does not equal to 0, to fulfill criteria #1

With the code below, I would be able to exclude CustID FFF and GGG when doing distinct count of CustID based on my criteria #1:

```
Select 
Country
, o.Year
, o.Month
, sum(o.Sales) 
, sum(o.Points)
, sum(o.Sales + o.Points) as 'TestSUM'
, o.OrderType

From FactOrders O
Join CustTable as C on o.CustID = c.CustID
and o.OrderType in (1,2,3) 

Group by 
Country
, o.Year
, o.Month
, o.OrderType
, c.CustID

having sum(o.Sales + o.Points) <> 0   

Order by
c.CustID
```

However, how I want my results to look like is actually this:

```
  Country   Year  Month  Distinct Count   Sales  
 Singapore  2018     10               6  2048.06 
 Singapore  2018     11               7  1996.61
```

How do I amend my script to remove the column of "CustID", "Point", "TestSUM", "OrderType" but still maintain my distinct count reflective of the criteria

```
having sum(o.Sales + o.Points) <> 0
```

**Details from comment:**

I want sales+points <>0 criteria applied per customer, but the results returned to not show lines by CustID when i remove CustID, Point, TestSum and OrderType from the group by and select, the sales+points<>0 criteria does not apply per customer anymore... the distinct count of CustID would include lines where sales+points<>0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly you can do this like below. Note that I removed the JOIN to CustTable as it was not used. You can keep it back if you do not have referential integrity between FactOrders and CustTable.

I moved your having to where as you are counting customers even if they have one row which is 0 and 0.

<kbd>**[See live demo](https://rextester.com/QMG5573)**</kbd>

```
  Select 
     Country=o.Country
     ,Year= o.Year
     ,Month= o.Month
     ,[Distinct Count]=Count(distinct custid)
     ,Sales= sum(o.Sales) 
From FactOrders O
where 
    o.OrderType in (1,2,3) and (o.Sales<>0 or o.Points<>0)
Group by 
   o.Country, o.Year, o.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces your demo results.

```
Select 
     Country=o.Country
     ,Year= o.Year
     ,Month= o.Month
     ,[Distinct Count]=Count(distinct custid)
     ,Sales= sum(o.Sales) 
From FactOrders O
where 
    o.OrderType in (1,2,3) 
and o.Sales + o.Points<>0
Group by 
   o.Country, o.Year, o.Month
```

However, that does not satisfy your stated requirement where Sales and Points may not both be 0.   If Sales = -10 and Points = 10, that will also add up to 0, even though neither equals 0.

The following should be what you're looking for:

```
Select 
     Country=o.Country
     ,Year= o.Year
     ,Month= o.Month
     ,[Distinct Count]=Count(distinct custid)
     ,Sales= sum(o.Sales) 
From FactOrders O
where 
    o.OrderType in (1,2,3) 
and o.Sales <> 0 and o.Points <> 0    --  because, -10 + 10 = 0
Group by 
   o.Country, o.Year, o.Month
```

Comment: you are right about the first option, i missed that out, but for this example it gives the correct answer, while the second script produced right distinct count of CustID but wrong sum of Sales because it excluded lines where only Sales =0 OR Points =0